# Spark pushed filters are not effective

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am running a simple count query against a parquet table the query goes as follow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parquet_table WHERE 
dt >= '2023-04-14T06:00:00Z' and dt < '2023-06-13T06:00:00Z' and 
car.type = 'auto' and car.platform = 'IOS' and at >= 1681452000000 
and at <= 1686636000000 ;
```

Where dt is a table partition.

Inspecting the plan I can notice that all filters are pushed down to the data source:

```
Scan parquet spark_catalog.default.parquet_table
Output [3]: [at#3L, car#5, dt#25]
Batched: true
Location: InMemoryFileIndex [s3a://...., ... 1439 entries]
PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(dt#25), (dt#25 >= 2023-04-14T06:00:00Z), (dt#25 < 2023-06-13T06:00:00Z)]
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(car.type), IsNotNull(car.platform), IsNotNull(at), EqualTo(car.type,auto), EqualTo(car.platform,IOS), GreaterThanOrEqual(at,1681452000000), LessThanOrEqual(at,1686636000000)]
ReadSchema: struct<at:bigint,car:struct<platform:string,type:string>>
```

However, when inspecting the number of rows of the parquet scan, I found that the rows are not really filtered according to the pushed filters and they are only so after spark filter.

[image]

Separately, shouldn't the optimizer be smart enough to completely remove the filter step since all filters have been pushed down?

I am using Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12

Comment: Provide full output of explain plan for this.

Answer (score 1):

Spark pushed filters may only do partial filtering on chunks of data, instead of applying the filter row-by-row.

For example, given chunk of data, check `IOS` is between the min and max `car.platform` values.

If it is, read the whole chunk (along with all the unwanted rows)
Otherwise, skip it.

I can't find documentation on this in Spark, but this is how the Apache Drill documentation [describes parquet filter pushdown](https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-filter-pushdown/).

This [Spark 3.2 API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/SupportsPushDownFilters.html) hints at this too.

> There are 3 kinds of filters:
>
> - pushable filters which don't need to be evaluated again after scanning.
> - pushable filters which still need to be evaluated after scanning, e.g. parquet row group filter.
> - non-pushable filters.

In my case, pushed filters reduced rows read from 1.4B down to 150M.
The final filtered result was 22M rows, so even though the pushed filters only partially filtered the data, they still significantly reduced the runtime.

Comment: I have found that the files I am processing only have one row group per file so I guess group filter can not be effective. However, I have tried to turn on spark.sql.parquet.recordLevelFilter.enabled with the vectorized reader disabled of course but the result wasn't too different

Comment: A separate question, do you sort the data in the parquet files by the filtered column?

Comment: Apparently there is sub-row-group indexing in parquet, that might be what you want here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26345